# How to create sprite from RenderTexture cocos2d-x v3.2?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to make a game that will take what users draw on their screens and create a sprite with a physics body. I looked around and I saw a tutorial that demonstrated this. Unfortunately the tutorial was made in Cocos2d-x v2.

http://build-failed.blogspot.com/2012/08/freehand-drawing-with-cocos2d-x-and.html

That is the tutorial that I am referring to.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Render_To_Texture

I tried to use that cocos2d-x tutorial to help me, but it has been labeled outdated (I tried it anyway and it didn't work). Is it still possible to allow the user to draw through this method? Or do I need to find another method to allow the user to draw the sprites? Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

```
void GameScene::onTouchMoved(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    Point start = touch->getLocation();
    start = Director::getInstance()->convertToGL(start);
    Point end = touch->getPreviousLocation();
    end = Director::getInstance()->convertToGL(end);

    target->begin();

    float distance = start.getDistance(end);

    for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++)
    {
        float difx = end.x - start.x;
        float dify = end.y - start.y;
        float delta = (float) i / distance;
        brush->setPosition(Point(start.x + (difx * delta), start.y + (dify * delta)));
        brush->visit();
    }
    target->end();
}

void GameScene::onTouchEnded(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    myObjectSprite = Sprite::createWithTexture(target->getSprite()->getTexture());
    myObjectSprite->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width / 2, visibleSize.height / 2));
    this->addChild(myObjectSprite);
}
```

This is what I gathered from those links. I can draw but there are a few problems.

1. The first attempt to draw always reflects horizontally over the center of the screen.
2. After a few drawings the fps begins to drop, and the app begins to take up a lot of memory and CPU usage.
3. The for loop in the onTouchMoved method is used because the onTouchEnded method isn't called fast enough, so there is often a large gap between each point that the onTouchMethod obtains. The loop is used to draw the brush sprites in a line between each point to prevent the gaps. However, for some reason it is not drawing in between the gaps.

Additionally, in the first link the person uses b2PolygonShape and b2FixtureDef from box2d. What are the new names of the classes in cocos2d-x v3?

Comment: What exactly didn't work? RenderTexture still works, and the tutorial from first link is pretty good, changes have beed made to Touch Mechanism, so you would have to make EventListeners rather than override onTouchMoved method. Also Box2D is now easier to use as it's integrated with the SceneWithPhysics(). Most of deprecated names are still defined as macros so you may use them if you find it difficult to learn new version of cocos2d-x